# Uploading Acceptance Criteria to VSTS through Excel bulk upload.

Tags: excel, azure-devops

We have starting adding Work Items to our backlog through excel upload, but the 'Acceptance Criteria' field doesn't want to work. The error says 'field not available for this type of work item, even though all our 'requirement' type work items in VSTS have AC.

Comment: Recommend adding a lot more detail and some examples of what you're uploading.

Answer (score 0):

By default the '`Acceptance Criteria`' field is not added in layout. So, to use the `Acceptance Criteria` field you need to add it to layout first:

1. **Create inherited process** based on the default CMMI process in your scenario. See [Create and manage inherited processes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/organizations/settings/work/manage-process?view=vsts) for details.
2. Add `Acceptance Criteria` field to layout
3. Change the process for your project (use the new created process)
4. Open Query in Excel  ->  Add/Modify the values of each filed ->
   Publish to update

[image]

Comment: @James Have you resolved the issue by above answer? any update?